# Return array in function pointer argument

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm having issues returning an array in a function argument; I'm going to jump straight to my example:
I'm declaring pointers before my function call and want to get arrays when the function is executed

```
double *x;
double *y;
myfunction(data,x,y);
printf("x[0] = %1.1f\n",x[0] );
```

Where myfunction is defined as:

```
void myfunction(CvMat * data, double *x, double *y){
    /* Some code */
    x = malloc(calculated_size*sizeof(double));
    y = malloc(calculated_size*sizeof(double));
    int k;
    for (k = 0;k < calculated_size; k++)
    {
        x[k] = p[0] ;
        y[k] = p[1] ;
    }
}
```

Ok I have remained very superficial to my problem in order to not overcomplicate things, but the main issue is I do not know the size my array will have before the function call (and I do not want to calculate the size beforehand).

This code compiles fine, but when I run it, I get a segmentation fault when printing x[0]. Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong? ;-)

Comment: I followed the link you gave to update my solution but I'm still not getting the desired result. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello! I've just rolled back your edit. Please do not "reforge" one question to another. If you solved your original question with on-site resources - superb, great! But if you now have **another** question, then please simply post **another question** and leave the old one as it is. Reforging an old question to another topic: (1)makes the title obsolete or wrong (2)makes the question hard to read (top 50% of text is trash) (3)makes most of current answers (and sometimes `tags` too) missed or odd or invalid (4)makes it overall harder to understand and to find/search